# Objective-C memory leak in loading remote content

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, cfnetwork

I try to load a plist file from my server. I can think of 2 ways to do that, but for both Instruments says there's huge memory leak :

```
NSData* plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

and

```
NSDictionary* updateDigest = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:updateURL] ];
```

The backtrace of the memory leak leads to __CFURLCache in CFNetwork and I am wondering if something can be done to fix the leak? Any other way to load a remote plist xml, without the memory leakage ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leak probably isn't coming from loading the data. It's probably from retaining the data elsewhere and not releasing it.

Comment: Yes Tom indeed, put by mistake retain to a property which had to only assign. Thanks :)